# reformatting text in a def function

Tags: python

```
def text_to_lines(text, max_length):
    return text


new_text1 = "ASDF is the sequence of letters that appear on the first four keys on the home row of a QWERTY"
new_text2 = "or QWERTZ keyboard. They are often used as a sample or test case or as random, meaningless"
new_text3 = "nonsense. It is also a common learning tool for keyboard classes, since all four keys are"
new_text4 = "located on Home row."
source_text = "ASDF is the sequence of letters that appear on the first four keys on the home row of a QWERTY or QWERTZ keyboard. They are often used as a sample or test case or as random, meaningless nonsense. It is also a common learning tool for keyboard classes, since all four keys are located on Home row."

print(source_text)
print()
print(text_to_lines(new_text1, 22))
print(text_to_lines(new_text2, 20))
print(text_to_lines(new_text3, 20))
print(text_to_lines(new_text4, 7))
```

I have to implement a function text_to_lines(text, max_length) which neatly formats the given text into lines of length max_length. Words should not be cut off, but moved to the next line when necessary. I tried this code above, but I dont understand how to fix the max length. The output of the function is a string where each line contains at most max_length characters such that no words are cut off.

Answer (score 0):

<version 2>
The function be like:

```py
def text_to_lines(text, max_length):
    new_text = ""
    res="    "
    for word in text.split(' '):
        if len(new_text)+len(word)+1 > max_length:
            res+=new_text+'\n'
            new_text = ""
        new_text += word + " "
    return res
```

hope i can help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the output is now just a part of the text : 
ASDF is the sequence
or QWERTZ keyboard.
nonsense. It is

Comment: I need every part of the text but formatting correctly

Comment: sorry about that, here is the new version

Comment: @Kariem check out the new version

Comment: ASDF is the sequence of letters that appear on the first four keys on the home row of a QWERTY o
r QWERTZ keyboard. They are often used as a sample or test case or as random, meaningless nonsen
se. It is also a common learning tool for keyboard classes, since all four keys are located on H
ome row.

ASDF is the sequence of letters that appear on the first four keys on the home row of a QWERTY
or QWERTZ keyboard. They are often used as a sample or test case or as random, meaningless
nonsense. It is also a common learning tool for keyboard classes, since all four keys are
located on Home

Comment: Home row. This should be the expected output in two seperate paragraphs

Comment: Ok i will fix it

Comment: Can you learn me how I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/textwrap.html) module might help here:

```py
source_text = "ASDF is the sequence of letters that appear on the first four keys on the home row of a QWERTY or QWERTZ keyboard. They are often used as a sample or test case or as random, meaningless nonsense. It is also a common learning tool for keyboard classes, since all four keys are located on Home row."

from textwrap import wrap
for line in wrap(source_text, 94):
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
ASDF is the sequence of letters that appear on the first four keys on the home row of a QWERTY
or QWERTZ keyboard. They are often used as a sample or test case or as random, meaningless
nonsense. It is also a common learning tool for keyboard classes, since all four keys are
located on Home row.
```

Comment: Thank u Terry Spotts, but I cant use a import function in this case